# Geometry in MySQL

Tags: mysql, geometry

I understood what `POINT()` is in `MySQL` but I just cant figure out what is this format means
`1 POINT (8.04665153 -44.39902520)` I have the following `CSV`

`104|104||CURR|N|14102|4428||71816|71816|1|1 POINT (8.04665153 -44.39902520)|`

I am using the following query to load the `CSV` into my table

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/data/disc/sad1.csv' INTO TABLE sad1 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' ENCLOSED BY '"' lines terminated by '\n' IGNORE 23 LINES
(@var1, @var2,@var3,@var4,@var5,@var6,@var7,@var8,@var9,@var10,@var11,@var12)
SET `house_number` = @var1,
    `range_low` = @var2,
    `range_high` = @var3,
    `status` = @var4,
    `unofficial_flag` = @var5,
    `rcl_id` = @var6,
    `rna_id` = @var7,
    `alt_id` = @var8,
    `se_row_id` = @var9,
    `id` = @var10,
    `audit_id` = @var11,
    `shape` = GeomFromText(@var12);
```

I am getting `NULL` for the `shape` field. When I changed `1 POINT (8.04665153 -44.39902520)` to `POINT (8.04665153 -44.39902520)` I am getting some data filled in. How should I treat the prefix `1` in the above data ?

Comment: Where does that CSV file come from? Do any rows contain a prefix other than `1` there? If not, perhaps substituting all `1 POINT` to `POINT` will be enough. Don't have any experience with spatial mysql, though.

Comment: No all rows has the number 1 on it.. I have substituted that as u said but I want to make sure it's rite...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no sure what this prefix `1` in ypur input data signifies. The well-known text representation of geometry, as defined in section 7 of the [SFA part 1 standard](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sfa), does not include such a prefix. It might be that this digit indicates the number of features. Or it might denote the integer code for the point type, as specified in table 7 from section 8.2.3 of that standard.

In any case, as long as the prefix is `1` in all the cases, and the creator of your input csv data does not provide additional details on the meaning of that value, your best bet is to simply drop these prefixes. You might do that using a preprocessing phase on the CSV, substituting `POINT` for `1 POINT` throughout the document. There is a remote chance that you might accidentially substitute an occurrence somewhere in a text column.

If you want to be safe, or want to avoid the extra step, you can also do the change in the SQL query, using an expression like this:

```
`shape` = GeomFromText(IF(@var12 LIKE '1 POINT%', SUBSTRING(@var12, 3), @var12))
```

This will check whether the corresponding column starts with `1 POINT`, and if so, omit the first two characters from the column text.